# Телеграм бот в несколько файлов

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всех приветствую, делаю бота на aiogram. Из-за специфического предназначения бота, его функционал должен иметь два режима работы "отправка сообщений целиком" и "отправка с эффектом печати". Для этого было решено разделить код на три файла main.py, func1.py, func2.py. В main.py пользователь посредством Inline кнопок должен выбрать режим работы бота.

К проблеме. Из-за малого опыта, я пока не очень догоняю, как можно из одного файла запустить код бота в другом. Долго гуглил, но так и не сообразил, как это сделать.

main.py

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, asyncio
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor, exceptions
import config
import scenario
import markups as mark
from time import sleep as sl
from config import TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def choice_effect(mes):

    choice_button=InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
    One = InlineKeyboardButton("Начать выполнение кода из func1.py", callback_data= "choice_one")
    choice_button.add(One)

    await bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, "Нажмите на кнопку для запуска кода из func1.py", reply_markup = choice_button)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="choice_")
async def call_back0(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    if call.data == 'choice_one':
        #После соблюдения условия должен выполняться код из func1.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

Файл с кодом для постепенного вывода сообщений.

func1.py

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, asyncio
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor, exceptions
import config
import scenario
import markups as mark
from time import sleep as sl


from config import TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

f = list(open ('file_with_text.txt', encoding = 'Windows-1251'))

@dp.message_handler("Пока не знаю, что сюда передать")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i < 7:
            orig_text = line
            msg = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'I')
            sl(0.1)
            tbp = orig_text[:1]
            for x in orig_text[1:]:
                try:
                    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id, text=f'{tbp}|')
                    sl(0.1)
                    tbp += x
                    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id, text=tbp)

                except exceptions.RetryAfter as e:
                    await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос состоит в том как вызвать метод/код из другого файла на питоне, то вы можете его подключить в main.py следующим образом (если они в одном каталоге):

```
from func1 import *
```

При этом вы сможете вызвать метод start расположенный func1.py. Но вам придется удалить как миниумум  следующий код из func1.py, так как при подключении файла они вызовутся автоматически.

```
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, что я не очень понимаю, как после выполнения условия из одного файла (то бишь нажатие кнопки), запустить работу блока кода из метода другого файла(то бишь заставить его начать отправлять сообщения).

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы просто хотите вызвать метод start(message: types.Message) в main.py. Тогда после условия if call.data == 'choice_one': можете вставить start(call.message). Так как напрямую метод вохможно не будет вызываться то я думаю можно удалить там строку @dp.message_handler("Пока не знаю, что сюда передать")

Comment: К сожалению, данный вариант не очень сработал. Но все еще пытаюсь что-то придумать.